# Binarize and SelectComponents gives incorrect output

Tags: image-processing

`Binarize` seems to be giving me incorrect output.

Overall, I am trying to identify characteristics of different objects in my images. I have a label image that corresponds to the positions of each of the different objects. For example, all pixels corresponding to object 1 have value 1; pixels corresponding to object 2 have value 2, etc. Background has value 0.

Please find an example 16-bit label image at https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwIO2.jpg (it's not scaled, so it looks all black). Here is a colorized version in which each pixel value corresponds to a different color (and 0 is black):

[image: example label image]

In order to identify all the pixels corresponding to object x, I have tried two ways (`labelImage` is the label image from above), one using `Binarize` and one using `PixelValuePositions`. Let's say I'm looking for object #136. Then with `Binarize`, I use

```
Binarize[labelImage, {136/2^16, 136/2^16}]
```

which outputs

[image: Binarize output image]

or with `PixelValuePositions`, I use

```
ppos = PixelValuePositions[labelImage, 136/2^16];
ReplacePixelValue[labelImage, ppos -> Cyan] // ImageAdjust
```

which outputs

[image: PixelValuePositions]

These are clearly different objects. When I look at the original image in ImageJ, the `PixelValuePositions` identifies the correct object, whereas `Binarize` identifies object #137. Any ideas on what's going on here?

UPDATE 1: (Another thought—I had forgotten about the built-in functions `MorphologicalComponents` and `ComponentMeasurements`, which can do much of what I’d like to do.)

UPDATE 2: I have been trying to use `SelectComponents` to get a label image containing only an object of interest. This seems to also give incorrect results in the same way that `Binarize` does. The command

```
SelectComponents[labelImage, #Label == 136 &] // ImageAdjust
```

Gives

[image: SelectComponents output]

Finally, this is a tangent, but SelectComponents also seems to be slow. The `AbsoluteTiming` for the above command is 0.466338, whereas the `AbsoluteTiming` for the following command using `PixelValuePositions` is 0.166369.

```
ReplacePixelValue[
  ConstantImage[0, ImageDimensions[objectIdentitiesImages[[1]]], 
   "Bit16"], 
  PixelValuePositions[labelImage, 136/2^16] -> Cyan] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Answer (score 6):

It's weird that you get any pixels a tall, because the value `136/2^16` isn't even *in* the image:

```
MemberQ[Flatten[DeleteDuplicates[ImageData[img]]], 136/2^16]
```

> False

My guess is that `PixelValuePositions` and `Binarize` round the value resp. thresholds to the closest possible pixel values. And (wild guess) `Binarize` probably takes the `Floor` of the lower and the `Ceiling` of the upper threshold, while `PixelValuePositions` probably rounds to the closest value.

If you use `136/(2^16 - 1)` instead (because the highest possible value in a 16 bit image, 2^16-1 is mapped to 1.0), you get the same object.

Comment: Thanks nikie. That sounds like a reasonable hypothesis. Mathematica seems to like rescaling images to values between 0 and 1, which is why I had to divide by 2^16 in the first place and which also seems to complicate things unnecessarily.

Comment: I agree, it's unfortunate that you can't turn off rescaling. You can use `imgInteger = img*65535;`, though, and only work with integers after that. You just have to be careful because some image processing functions (like `ImageAdd`, IIRC?) clip the output to the range 0..1

Comment: You can use, e.g., `Clip` to preprocess the image.